# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables when trying to secure query

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

I wanted to secure my php code from sql injections using the bind_param functions and I came across this error. I checked the amount of ?'s and bind_params but they are both equal, so I have no idea what I have done wrong.

I think this is the part the error comes from:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$searchText = $_POST['search'];
echo "You searched for: " . htmlspecialchars($searchText, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM recources WHERE recource_title LIKE '%?%' OR recource_topic LIKE '%?%' OR recource_author LIKE '%?%' OR recource_description LIKE '%?%';");
$query->bind_param('s', $searchText, $searchText, $searchText, $searchText);
$query->execute();
```

Edit: I tried using `$query->bind_param('ssss'` instead of 1 s, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unquote your placeholders and concatenate the wildcards in the binding. Your error is because you have no placeholders in your query.

Once you correct the placeholders you'll need to correct the binding call. The first parameter is what each variable being bound is so:

```
bind_param('s'
```

should really be

```
bind_param('ssss'
```

(because you have 4 variables) A Full example:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM recources WHERE recource_title LIKE ? OR recource_topic LIKE ? OR recource_author LIKE ? OR recource_description LIKE ?;");
$wild_var = '%' . $searchText . '%';
$query->bind_param('ssss', $wild_var, $wild_var, $wild_var, $wild_var);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: I still get the "Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters" error, really weird.

Comment: Is that a copy of the exact error message?

Comment: Oh well I think I did not saved the file the correct way but I still get an error saying "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference" and then pointing at this line "$query->bind_param('ssss'". Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, the finicky mysqli, give the update a try.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you so much!